# How to combine and test google dataproc --initialization-actions

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

Debug is slow. Unclear if accepts multiple args. Docstring is wrong/non-standard.

For example can we do:

--initialization-actions a b c

When it fails, how to debug in seconds not minutes ... i.e. as script not full create step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get debug time down to seconds, I'd suggest creating a vanilla cluster and running your init action as a regular script on master node via SSH under `sudo`.

For example:

```
gcloud compute ssh my-cluster-m
gsutil cp gs://bucket/path-to-init-action.sh .
sudo init-action.sh
```

As you make iterations, you may have to add flags to not fail for already installed components.

Answer (score 8):

You can specify multiple [Initialization actions](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions) using [comma-separated list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create):

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create ...\
    --initialization-actions=<init_action_1>,<init_action_2>,...,<init_action_n>
```

If any Initialization action fails then Dataproc will return error with path to Initialization actions logs, which you can use to debug failure.

If you are writing your own Initialization action you can follow [best practices](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#best-practices) and add `set -euxo pipefail` statement at [the beginning](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/6f39e3b041d3848822c3fbacc20530209cd19db6/connectors/connectors.sh#L3) of your Initialization action to make it fail fast and print more information during execution which will simplify debugging in case of failure.